# How to make a scroll footer to fixed then back to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

Hello all, I have seen all of these sticky footer script and sticky sidebar scripts! what I want is something similar, I have a long page with a footer and then more content below the footer, I would like the page to only show the footer when the content reaches the footer, once the footer shows on the screen, it gets fixed to the bottom so I can keep on scrolling the page and view the "more content" and when scrolling back up, the footer detaches from fixed at the bottom back to normal!

I have attached a screenshot to maybe help explaining it better!

Comment: have you tried anything? can you share your code in Jsfiddle?

Comment: something like this http://jsbin.com/omanut/2 but instead of a header! I want it in the footer! the footer should not be sticky at first, but once it shows in the page, it gets fixed to the bottom so you can scroll for more content! does that makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it requires some steps...

- Get how much window has scrolled.
- check if it has scrolled beyond the point we want our footer to start acting as fixed.
- That point is a sum of window height - footer height.
- if that point is again gone back to then make it as it was.
- Add function to scroll event. So which check everything and does the work if needed.

**See demo here**: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/MgQQm/2/embedded/result/

**See code here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/MgQQm/2/

```
$footer = $('#footer');
$win = $(window);
var ipos = $footer.offset().top;
var wpos, space, width;
width = $footer.width();

function h(e) {
    wpos = $win.scrollTop();
    space = $win.height() - $footer.height();
    if ((wpos + space) > ipos) {
        $footer.addClass('fixed');
        $footer.width(width);
    } else {
        $footer.removeClass('fixed');

    }
}


$(window).scroll(h);
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! just a quick question! it seems to work great in IE, Firefox, Chrome, but in IE and FF, when the footer changes to fixed, it stutters a bit then gets fixed! Do you know why?

Comment: i think it's because getting the actual numbers in dom/css/js/across browser is one retarded thing to do.

Comment: Is there a way to make it not stutter? tried hard coding the height in, no luck! in chrome, it works great, only in IE and FF it stutters ;(

Comment: Got it working, it was some CSS issues with relative and absolute positioning! thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div id="content"></div>
 <div id="moreContent"></div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

css

```
 #content {
   height:1000px;
   width:400px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   background-color:red;
}
#moreContent{
   height:500px;
   width:450px;
   margin:0px 0px 100px 0px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 0;
   background-color:yellow;
 }
#footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   width:400px;
   left: 8px;
   right: 0;
   height: 100px;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color:blue;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vErBy/)

Answer (score 0):

In css itself before, you may keep it to `position:fixed;`.

Or use JQuery for that,

```
$('footer').css({position:'fixed'});
```

Or pure js,

```
document.getElementByTagName('footer').style.position = 'fixed';
```

To make it scrollable later use jQuery,

```
 $('footer').css({position:'relative'});
```

Or use javascript,

```
 document.getElementByTagName('footer').style.position = 'relative';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css for footer element

```
.sticky {
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    background: #F6D565;
    padding: 25px 0;
    top:700px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

For demo chk this  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/vErBy/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: he wants it to happen once user has scrolled to certain height